# Find $E[X|Y=y]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed

Tags: probability

Suppose that two normally distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, with $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,5)$.

The conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y = y$ can be defined as

$E[X|Y=y] = \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} x f_{X|Y} (x|y) dx$ .

Furthermore we have the formula $f_{X|Y} (x|y)= \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y (y)}$.

Since $f_Y (y)$ is known, how can we find $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ to obtain $E[X|Y=y]$ ?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, then how are they related? Is there any more information?

Comment: Yes, $Y = X + Z$, where $Z \sim N(0,4)$.

Comment: We're still missing an information concerning the independence (or not) between $X$ and $Z$. You can derive the joint distribution of (X,Y) from the one of (X,Z), and then use the formula I give in my answer or just use standard formulae of deriving conditional distribution.

Comment: @WNG We can assume that $X$ and $Z$ are independent. Is this sufficient information for computing the joint distribution of (X,Y)? There is no joint distribution known of (X,Z) and no correlation between $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively easy way to compute this if $(X,Y)$ is a normal vector with distribution :

$$E(X|Y)=\mu_x + (Y-\mu_y)\frac{\rho_{xy}\sigma_{x}}{\sigma_{y}} $$

as the comment states, you do not provide the relation between $X$ and $Y$. The vector formed by two normal distributions is not a normal vector in the general case, so you need to know more about *how* $X$ and $Y$ depend on each other

Comment: $Y = X + Z$, where $Z \sim N(0,4)$.